# Tableau - How to move the order of parameters in Storyboard

Tags: tableau-api

Hi I created a tableau report with the following parameters in a worksheet (see below). After I added a Storyboard the order of parameter changed. Is there a way to modify the order of parameter in Story board?[image: Storyboard Parameters]

[image: Worksheet Parameters]

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the worksheet into a Dashboard, there you can modify the order of parameters as you want, and then add that dashboard into a Story Board.

Comment: The 2nd image I provided it the order of parameters in each worksheets.

Comment: I though you order the parameters in the worksheet after add it into the story board.

Comment: Dashboard is fine I can rearrange the order of parameters, but its weird in story board it wont let me rearrange the order of parameters.